# How do i email the results of a wget download via linux mail command?

Tags: php, linux, scripting, email, wget

I am required to write a script that would download a file (based on a provided url to that file) using wget and then pipe the result to the mail command so that it can be mailed  to a provided email address. This will be used in a php based project.

"Piping the result" preferably would be a built link to the file on the server, so that the recipient of the mail could just click the link and get the file locally.

Anyone have experience in this area of combining commands they would share?

Comment: I don't understand, are you asking how to do `wget URL | mail -s "subject" email@address` ???

Comment: Do you want to download from an external url, store that file on an intranet server and then send a link to that local (cached) file to someone "within" the intranet?

Comment: so what, you want to write this in PHP? or some shell scripting language? If the latter, derobert has the right idea, and it should be trivially simple. If you want to write it in PHP however, that might be more complicated....

Comment: @derobert : i have tried that and yes the mails send nicely but there is nothing in the mail body or as attachment. Thus i figured there must be more to it. A more complex command?
@VolkerK : that is a basic rundown of what is expected.
@Thomi : the simplest way would suit me best but i have been given additional instructions by the higher-ups to have it done in primarily php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pseudocode, might even work directly, save it to a file and call it with 2 parameters, first one is the url of the remote file you wish to download, second is the email where to send the notification.

LOCALPATH variable should be a directory which is accessible from www and LOCALURL should match that location.

```
#!/bin/bash
URL=$1
FILE=`basename $URL`
EMAIL=$2
LOCALURL=http://yourdomain.com/files
LOCALPATH=/var/www/html/files
cd $LOCALPATH
wget $URL
cat<<END|mail -s "New file available" ${EMAIL}
Hello, 

   your new file can be downloaded now from:

   ${LOCALURL}/${FILE}

Thanks!
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [PHP binding for CURL](http://gr2.php.net/curl)